# How to show sticky menu in all other pages except home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I would like to show sticky menu in all other pages except home page . How can I do that ? Please help [Please see my site here](http://development.hostroom.in/spantronics/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide sticky header using css

```
.page-id-94 .is-sticky {
    display: none;
}
```

Page ID - .page-id-9 -> It is unique to front page that you are using.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Dear Prep, Thanks for the response . I updated the CSS , but still it shows the header . Please check the link

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.page-id-9 #Top_bar.is-sticky { display: none; } } Please try this css. This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help - but still it is not working . Could you please take a look at the web site ...

Comment: I checked the website again and looks like the sticky header is hidden now. Was there any cache or something? How did you achieve that? :-)

Comment: Hi Perp - now sticky menu is hidden in all pages - we needs to hide it only in home page .. Could you please advice .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.home #Top_bar.is-sticky{
    position: relative !important;
}
```

It's better to use .home class instead of .page-id-XXX since there is a possibility the homepage may change id.

Comment: Thanks frederikvdbe, I tried this - but not working - please check the site

Comment: the .is-sticky class doesn't get added anymore so you must have made some changes to the JS? Above code should work just fine...

Comment: I did not do any changes in JS